# Error onchange event on jquery ui slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 slider (using jquery-ui slider)

```
<div class="slider-loan-tenure" data-min="5" data-max="35" data-value="25"></div>
<div class="slider-loan-amount" data-min="10" data-max="80" data-value="80"></div>
```

And my script

```
var $slider1 = $(".slider-loan-amount").slider({
    value: $(".slider-loan-amount").data("value"),
    min: $(".slider-loan-amount").data("min"),
    max: $(".slider-loan-amount").data("max"),
    orientation: "horizontal",
    animate: !0,
    range: "min"
});

var $slider2 = $(".slider-loan-tenure").slider({
    value: $(".slider-loan-tenure").data("value"),
    min: $(".slider-loan-tenure").data("min"),
    max: $(".slider-loan-tenure").data("max"),
    orientation: "horizontal",
    animate: !0,
    range: "min",
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.value > 30) {
            $slider1.slider("option", "max", 60);
        } else {
            $slider1.slider("option", "max", 80);
        }
        $slider1.slider("value", $slider1.slider("value")); //force the view refresh, re-setting the current value
    }  
});
```

[image: bug]

When I change value on loan-tenure > 30, loan-amount can't update max=60. How to fix it?

Comment: Code is working fine, whats the issue you are facing?

Comment: When I change slider1 from 25 to 31, slider2 never change to 60

Comment: I tried with your code and the max value is getting reset to 60 once i change the other slider to more than 30. Check the answer below, will delete it once  you can explain the issue

Comment: is the issue resolved?